# Can we promote Magento Developer event?

Tags: discussion

When I speak about Magento Developer events, I think about the non-profit events like the Hackathon, not the Meet Magento or Imagine. The Hackathon is definitively destinated for the developers, done by volunteers developers and to help to improve developers skills and the community. It's like a Stack Exchange place but more human :-)

Comment: It's any interesting proposal.